# required=False not working with update_or_create in ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API where I get some data with user_id field. If given user_id exist in DB it update rest of the data else it will create new data. Here my code:

**serializers.py**

```
class DataUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'user_id', 'balance', 'device_id', 'platform')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data_update, created = User.objects.update_or_create(user_id=validated_data['user_id'],
                                                          defaults={
                                                              'first_name': validated_data['first_name'],
                                                              'last_name': validated_data['last_name'],
                                                              'email': validated_data['email'],
                                                              'balance': validated_data['balance'],
                                                              'device_id': validated_data['device_id'],
                                                              'platform': validated_data['platform'],

                                                          }
                                                          )

        return data_update
```

**views.py**

```
class data_update(APIView):

    permission_classes = (Check_API_KEY_Auth,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = DataUpdateSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            username = request.data['user_id']
            User.objects.filter(user_id=username).update(username=username)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

email, first_name and last_name are optional and can be blank in DB or in serializer.

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    balance = models.FloatField()
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

**Problem:**

Everything is working fine but if I don't pass email, first_name or last_name, it gives error: key_error  and if I provide these fields with blank value "", this give error  cannot be blank

Comment: Do the fields email, first_name and last_name have blank=True in the User model?

Comment: I have extended django default User model, I have not made any change in existing fields.

Comment: Can you add that model?

Comment: models.py added. please check

Answer (score 2):

I see various problems in your code.

- In the declaration of CharField in the model, you don't have `blank=True`. Hence, they simply cannot be blank in the DB, whatever you do above.
- Be careful when using a very basic `APIView` and manipulating the seralizer yourself. Your view is called "Update" but it does both "create" and "update". These are two different things, usually handled by two different routes.
- The usage you make of your serializer `DataUpdateSerializer(data=request.data)` is the usage for a CREATE, not an UPDATE, where you pass the instance of the relevant model object as first argument.
- The usage you make of `objects.update_or_create` must be checked. You basically make a queryset filtering using fields that may or may not be present, whose values may or may not have been changed, and if by any chance that filtering makes any sense, and you get nothing in return, then you create the object...

I would suggest to split the routes. Make a `ListAPIView` where you can CREATE, and a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` taking the `user_id` as parameter in your REST route, and simply declare the serializer class in the views. Then, use the `create` and `update` methods of the serializer itself. However, if everything is simply declared, you'd rarely need to write anything in these methods.

Comment: I know I should use create and update but then I will have to use post and patch/put methods for both case. data source don't if user already exist. how will source know which method to send in request.

Comment: Well that's the life of decoupling data and its consumption. Hit your endpoint with an unknown username -> 404, ok -> create with the list endpoint...

Comment: Formally checking a resource exists is the role of one request, and updating a resource is another one. Each with its consistent response code explaining what happened.